# ingress in microk8s doesnt assigne an ADDRESS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, microk8s

My problem is why ingress doesn't assign an Address for the services.

First, I create 3 deployments:

```bash
kubectl create deployment cheddar --image=errm/cheese:cheddar
kubectl create deployment stilton --image=errm/cheese:stilton
kubectl create deployment wensleydale --image=errm/cheese:Wensleydale
```

Then, I expose those 3 deployments:

```
kubectl expose deployment cheddar --port=80                  
kubectl expose deployment stilton --port=80                  
kubectl expose deployment wensleydale --port=80
```

After that, I apply my ingress.yaml with `kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml`, the ingress.yaml content is:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cheddar
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: cheddar.127.0.0.1.nip.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: cheddar
            port:
              number: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: stilton
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: stilton.127.0.0.1.nip.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: stilton
            port:
              number: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: wensleydale
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: wensleydale.127.0.0.1.nip.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: wensleydale
            port:
              number: 80
---
```

But when I route these paths, the result would still be `404-nginx`

The `kubectl get ingress` returns:

```
NAME          CLASS   HOSTS                          ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
cheddar       nginx   cheddar.127.0.0.1.nip.io                 80      43s
stilton       nginx   stilton.127.0.0.1.nip.io                 80      43s
wensleydale   nginx   wensleydale.127.0.0.1.nip.io             80      43s
```

NOTE1: I'm using microk8s on Ubuntu. My cluster version is: `v1.21.7-3+7700880a5c71e2`

```
➜  ~ k get no
NAME   STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
ali    Ready    <none>   8d    v1.21.7-3+7700880a5c71e2

➜  ~ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21+", GitVersion:"v1.21.7-3+7700880a5c71e2", GitCommit:"7700880a5c71e25c44491ef5c7d7fb30527d8337", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-11-17T22:07:23Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21+", GitVersion:"v1.21.7-3+7700880a5c71e2", GitCommit: "7700880a5c71e25c44491ef5c7d7fb30527d8337", GitTreeState:"clean," BuildDate:"2021-11-17T22:02:47Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

NOTE2: I've already enabled the ingress extension by this command:

```bash
microk8s enable ingress
```

Comment: you should take a look into ingress controller logs

Answer (score 2):

If you're using this cluster bare-metal, you'll have to use something like metallb. Kubernetes does not implement network load balancers and therefore, will not be able to assign an ip address to your ingress.

Since you're using microk8s, you can use `microk8s enable metallb`

If you're using aws, gcp, aks, you'll find it in their documentation.

For bare-metal see the following :
https://metallb.org/